# Swift Custom Pie Chart - Strange behavior cutting transparent circle from multiple UIBezierPaths

Tags: swift, uikit

Creating a custom pie chart / doughnut style graph with Swift, and am running into a strange problem when trying to cut the hole out of the doughnut. I've tried variations on center and radius for the second UIBezierPath, but I haven't been able to accomplish a clean cut hole from the center. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Subclass of UIView:

```
import UIKit

public class DoughnutView: UIView {

public var data: [Float]? {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

public var colors: [UIColor]? {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

@IBInspectable public var spacerWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

@IBInspectable public var thickness: CGFloat = 20 {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard data != nil && colors != nil else {
        return
    }

    guard data?.count == colors?.count else {
        return
    }

    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: bounds.size.height / 2.0)
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0
    let total = data?.reduce(Float(0)) { $0 + $1 }
    var startAngle = CGFloat(Float.pi)

    UIColor.clear.setStroke()

    for (key, value) in data!.enumerated() {
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(2.0 * Float.pi) * CGFloat(value / total!)

        let doughnut = UIBezierPath()
        doughnut.move(to: center)
        doughnut.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

        let hole = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius - thickness, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        hole.move(to: center)
        doughnut.append(hole)
        doughnut.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        doughnut.close()
        doughnut.lineWidth = spacerWidth
        colors?[key].setFill()

        doughnut.fill()
        doughnut.stroke()

        startAngle = endAngle
    }
}

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
}
```

And then a ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var doughnut: DoughnutView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    doughnut.data = [3, 14, 5]
    doughnut.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.blue]

    view.backgroundColor = .purple

}

}
```

The result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want this:

[image: pie chart]

The problem is that `addArc` creates, well, an **arc**, not a wedge. That is, it creates a path that traces part of a circle, without radial segments going to or from the center of the circle. Since you haven't been careful adding those radial segments, when you call `close()`, you get straight lines where you don't want them.

I guess you're trying to add those radial segments with your `move(to:)` calls, but you haven't done everything necessary to make that work.

Anyway, this can be done more simply. Start with an arc tracing the outer edge of the slice, then add an arc tracing the inner edge of the slice in the opposite direction. `UIBezierPath` will automatically connect the end of the first arc to the start of the second arc with a straight line, and `close()` will connect the end of the second arc to the start of the first arc with another straight line. Thus:

```
let slice = UIBezierPath()
slice.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius,
    startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
slice.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius - thickness,
    startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
slice.close()
```

That said, we can improve your `draw(_:)` method in some other ways:

- We can use `guard` to rebind `data` and `colors` to non-optionals.
- We can also `guard` that `data` is not empty.
- We can reduce `radius` by `spacerWidth` to avoid clipping the stroked borders. (You changed the stroke color to `.clear` in your question's code, but your image shows it as `.white`.)
- We can use `CGFloat` uniformly to have fewer conversions.
- We can divide `total` by 2π once instead of multiplying every `value` by 2π.
- We can `zip(colors, data)` into a sequence instead of using `enumerated()` and subscripting `colors`.

Thus:

```
public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count
        else { return }

    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: bounds.size.height / 2.0)
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0 - spacerWidth
    let total: CGFloat = data.reduce(0) { $0 + CGFloat($1) } / (2 * .pi)
    var startAngle = CGFloat.pi

    UIColor.white.setStroke()

    for (color, value) in zip(colors, data) {
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(value) / total

        let slice = UIBezierPath()
        slice.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        slice.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius - thickness, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
        slice.close()

        color.setFill()
        slice.fill()

        slice.lineWidth = spacerWidth
        slice.stroke()

        startAngle = endAngle
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a fantastic answer, Rob. Thank you for not only providing a beautiful solution to this, but also for your explanations, and for the suggestions on how to improve the guard statement, casting, and the geometric math. This is by far the best answer I've received on StackOverflow.